# Как можно контролировать выполнение анимаций?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

У меня есть вот такой код

```
class test_mynu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, arr="", parent=None):
        super(test_mynu, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!
        #------menu_pos_block------
        self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #------menu_pos_block_layout------
        self.menu_pos_block_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.menu_pos_block)  
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_pos_block_layout")
        #------menu_pos_label------
        self.menu_pos_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos_label)
        #------ADD------
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.menu_pos_block)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # number of radio
    def num(self):
        return 3
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             ######
        #------layout------
        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)  
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        #------menu_block------
        menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block.setObjectName(u"menu_block")
        layout_block.addWidget(menu_block)             ######
        #------menu_layout------
        menu_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block)  
        menu_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_layout")

        self.menu_but = []
        self.menu_pos = []
        for e in range(self.num()):
            #------menu_pos_block------
            menu_pos_block = test_mynu("menu_{}".format(e))
            self.menu_pos.append(menu_pos_block)
            #------ADD------
            menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos[e])
        #------menu_block_but------
        self.menu_block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu_block_but.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but")
        menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_block_but)             ######
        #------menu_block_but_layout------
        menu_block_but_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.menu_block_but)  
        menu_block_but_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but_layout")
        #------menu_but_radio------
        for e in range(self.num()):
            menu_but_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(e))
            menu_but_radio.setObjectName("radio_but_{}".format(e))
            self.menu_but.append(menu_but_radio)
            self.menu_but[e].toggled.connect(self.menu_animation)
            #------ADD------
            menu_block_but_layout.addWidget(self.menu_but[e])
        menu_block_content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block_content.setObjectName(u"menu_block_content")
        menu_layout.addWidget(menu_block_content)             ######
        #------menu_content_layout------
        menu_content_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block_content)  
        menu_content_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_content_layout")
        #------menu_label------
        menu_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        menu_label.setText('text, text text, text')
        menu_content_layout.addWidget(menu_label)
    def menu_animation(self):
        print("--x--")
        self.toggle_animations = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        for d in range(self.num()):
            print(str(d)+"_but_"+str(self.menu_but[d].isChecked()))
            print(str(d)+"_men_"+str(self.menu_pos[d]._expand))
            self.menu_pos[d].raise_()
            if self.menu_but[d].isChecked():
                self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.menu_pos[d], b"pos");
                self.anim.setDuration(1000);
                self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() - self.menu_pos[d].width(), self.menu_pos[d].y()));
                self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() +self.menu_block_but.width(), self.menu_pos[d].y()));
                #self.anim.start();
                self.menu_pos[d]._expand = True
            elif self.menu_pos[d]._expand and (not self.menu_but[d].isChecked()):
                self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.menu_pos[d], b"pos");
                self.anim.setDuration(1000);
                self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() +self.menu_block_but.width(), self.menu_pos[d].y()));
                self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() - self.menu_pos[d].width(), self.menu_pos[d].y()));
                #self.anim.start();
                self.menu_pos[d]._expand = False
                self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(self.anim)
            self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(self.anim)
        self.toggle_animations.start()
        print("--x--")


StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И мне нужно чтобы если я переключаю с menu_0 на menu_1 то вначале код должен скрыть menu_0 а после окончания анимаций включалась анимация появления menu_1
Примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то код устанавливает только одну анимацыю на одну кнопку и меняет виджеты как то хоатично. Можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: Не по теме. Какой странный `qss` `#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget`, если виджетам указывать `objectName`, то можно это имя в `qss` через `#` использовать как это было с `centralwidget`

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить лучше, что и когда должно происходить. Может приведете изображения, которые продемонстрируют, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick Я добавил иллюстрацию

Comment: @gil9red это мой дефолтный qss я его использую что бы отличать один qwidget от другого без особой заморочки с именами. это довольно удобно на начальных стадиях писаний qt кода. Ну по крайней мере для меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал изменения

- Добавил сохранение начальных позиций `menu`, чтобы знать куда их возвращать
- Сделал упорядочивание `menu`, чтобы меню с `_expand = True` было первым, тогда при анимации оно сначала поедет, а после тот, чей radio-button возведен
- Рефакторинг кода

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint


class test_mynu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, arr="", parent=None):
        super(test_mynu, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!
        #------menu_pos_block------
        self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #------menu_pos_block_layout------
        self.menu_pos_block_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.menu_pos_block)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_pos_block_layout")
        #------menu_pos_label------
        self.menu_pos_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos_label)
        #------ADD------
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.menu_pos_block)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # number of radio
    def num(self):
        return 3
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_animations = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             ######
        #------layout------
        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        #------menu_block------
        menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block.setObjectName(u"menu_block")
        layout_block.addWidget(menu_block)             ######
        #------menu_layout------
        menu_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block)
        menu_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_layout")

        self.menu_but = []
        self.menu_pos = []
        self.menu_by_pos = None

        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_pos_block = test_mynu("menu_{}".format(i))
            self.menu_pos.append(menu_pos_block)
            menu_layout.addWidget(menu_pos_block)

        #------menu_block_but------
        self.menu_block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu_block_but.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but")
        menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_block_but)             ######
        #------menu_block_but_layout------
        menu_block_but_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.menu_block_but)
        menu_block_but_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but_layout")
        #------menu_but_radio------
        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_but_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(i))
            menu_but_radio.setObjectName("radio_but_{}".format(i))
            menu_but_radio.toggled.connect(self.menu_animation)

            self.menu_but.append(menu_but_radio)
            menu_block_but_layout.addWidget(menu_but_radio)

        # Связывание меню к кнопкам и наоборот
        self.menu_by_but = dict()
        self.but_by_menu = dict()
        for i in range(self.num()):
            but = self.menu_but[i]
            menu = self.menu_pos[i]

            self.menu_by_but[menu] = but
            self.but_by_menu[but] = menu

        menu_block_content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block_content.setObjectName(u"menu_block_content")
        menu_layout.addWidget(menu_block_content)             ######
        #------menu_content_layout------
        menu_content_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block_content)
        menu_content_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_content_layout")
        #------menu_label------
        menu_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        menu_label.setText('text, text text, text')
        menu_content_layout.addWidget(menu_label)

    def menu_animation(self):
        print("--x--")

        self.toggle_animations.clear()

        # Запоминаем положения menu
        if not self.menu_by_pos:
            self.menu_by_pos = dict()
            for menu in self.menu_pos:
                self.menu_by_pos[menu] = menu.pos()

        # Хитрая сортировка, что сначала вернет элемент с _expand = True
        for menu in sorted(self.menu_pos, key=lambda x: x._expand):
            but = self.menu_by_but[menu]

            print(but.objectName() + " -> " + str(but.isChecked()))
            print(menu.objectName() + " -> " + str(menu._expand))
            menu.raise_()
            menu._expand = but.isChecked()

            if but.isChecked():
                start_pos = self.menu_by_pos[menu]
                end_pos = QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() +self.menu_block_but.width(), menu.y())
            else:
                start_pos = menu.pos()
                end_pos = self.menu_by_pos[menu]

            anim = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"pos")
            anim.setDuration(1000)
            anim.setStartValue(start_pos)
            anim.setEndValue(end_pos)

            self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(anim)

        self.toggle_animations.start()
        print("--x--")


StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Демонстрация:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMy72.gif

Comment: Я не уверен решило ли это мою проблему так как я заметил что в if у меня есть некоторые пробемы. возможно я мог бы их решить с помощью `num = int(self.sender().objectName()) if self.menu_but[num].isChecked(): elif not self.menu_but[num].isChecked():`  Но точно сказать не могу потому что если я использую  lambda то sender() перестает работать.

Comment: @orlatym, обновил ответ

Comment: я вставил `self.toggle_animations` в `MainWindow` после строки `super().__init__(parent)` и заменил функцию menu_animation но у меня срабатывает только первая анимация появления. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgYsb.gif а второй нету.

Comment: @orlatym, а что должно происходить при клике на 0, на 1, или 2? Запустил я код, у меня есть 3 menu. Тыкают на кнопку 0 и menu_0 должен заехать в `text, text...`? А если тыкну на 1, то menu_0 возвращается на старое место и в `text, text...` едет `menu_1`? И так аналогично для 3?

Comment: Вначале все radio не активны. при первом нажатий на radio0-2 (от 0 до 2) выдвигается menu номер которого равен активному radio с левой стороны на правую.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgYsb.gif) когда я переключаю с одного radio на другой например с 2 на 1 то предыдущие активное menu_2 двигается на левую сторону а после окончания анимаций menu_1 двигается на правую сторону (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyPLt.gif) и тоже самое происходит при каждом переключении radio.

Comment: @orlatym, сделал. Блоки катаются. Еще, я сделал немного рефакторинга, пожалуйста, придерживайтесь его, а то в коде сложно разбираться :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. код работает но я заметил некую пролему. Код исполняет все три анимаций по очереди. что означает что иногда случается небольшая задержа в выполнении анимаций. так как если `radio_but_0 = True radio_but_1 = False radio_but_2 = False / radio_but_0 = False radio_but_1 = False radio_but_2 = True` будет означать что menu_0 двигается в лево тратя 1s menu_1 стоит на месте 1s а menu_2 двигается в право за 1s

Comment: @orlatym, посмотрите в документации по поводу анимации, я этим не занимался, поэтому мне как и вам пришлось бы в доку лезть :)

Comment: Ну я смог кое как решить эту проблему   `self.num = 0
  self.menu_pos_ter = []
 
 def menu_animation(self):
  self.num =self.num+1
  self.toggle_animations.clear()
  
  num = int(self.sender().objectName())
  self.menu_pos_ter.append(self.menu_pos[num])
  
  for menu in sorted(self.menu_pos_ter, key=lambda x: x._expand):`